# Summoning animated series with a blue mammal

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime, cartoon

I used to watch a cartoon/anime style TV show when I was younger and I can't remember the name. It was animated like an action series like *He-Man* or *Dragon Ball*, but it had teenagers as protagonists. I remember that one of them could summon, from a pendant, a blue mammal (I say mammal cause I don't remember) possibly a tiger/lion, and they where like imaginary or from another dimension. I think the title was like a play on word for "Imaginary".

Sorry for being so vague about it, but I don't remember much and Google hasn't been useful either.

Comment: "When I was younger" is going to be **very different** depending on if you are currently 70 or 17.  Please could you try to narrow the date range down for those of us who do not know your personal information.

Answer (score 7):

*Magi-Nation* (2007), possibly.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001475/):

> Three thousand years ago in the Moonlands, the evil Shadow Magi Agram was sealed inside the planet's Core by the Core Glyph and the Dreamstones which provided its power. Now he plans to escape by using his Shadow Geysers to weaken his prison in order to bring the Moonlands under his control, and only a Magi known as the "Final Dreamer" can stop him. A young boy from Earth, Tony Jones, is summoned into the Moonlands as he is believed to be this Final Dreamer. He joins forces with the apprentice Magi, Edyn, and the Shadow Stalker, Strag, on a mission to gather the Dreamstones before Agram is set free. Using the Book of Elders, the three travel through the Moonlands while combating the forces of Agram and gaining an ever-growing collection of Dream Creatures from the Moonlands that they visit.

The blue mammal can be seen in the picture below, and there's a play on words between "imagination" and "Magi-Nation".

[image: main characters and their monsters]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure around what years you were “younger”...

Possible match: “Visionaries: Knights of the Magical Light”

It doesn’t seem to match since the main characters are not teenagers, but the leader of the heroes, Leoric, summons a blue lion from his chest emblem:

[image: blue warrior]

Comment: Oh man, I used to love this show. I used to have some of the figures with holographic images on their chest. I think I had the guy with the staff too.